# Select rows including integer but no letter from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Raw dataframe (df):

```
     A       B
0    1      green
1    2s     red
2    s      blue
3    4.3.4  yellow
4    0#     black
5    0.3    white
```

Expected dataframe (df) after selecting:

```
     A       B
0    1      green
3    4.3.4  yellow
4    0#     black
5    0.3    white
```

The type of column A is string.

I have no idea how to use regex/`str.contains()` to get the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a character class `[a-zA-Z]` to match the letters and inverse the selection with `~`.

```
df[~df['A'].str.contains('[a-zA-Z]')]
Out: 
       A       B
0      1   green
3  4.3.4  yellow
4     0#   black
5    0.3   white
```